# How to fix SharePoint designer workflow publishing issue?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, designer, sharepoint-designer

I have created the list workflow and just printing the history log to print a test message. I am trying to publish the workflow using my account but it always returning me below warning error message.

> You do not have permission to do this operation. Ask your site
> administrator to change your permissions and then try again, or log on
> with a user account that has this permission. To log on with a
> different user account click OK.

I did below workaround but did not get work:

1. Checked the site permissions for my account, all permissions are working correctly. I have full control, design and contribute access.
2. Checked the permissions for SharePoint designer, this is working fine. I am Primary administrator from central admin.
3. Checked the application pool. This is working fine.
4. Reset the IIS.
5. Also restarted the server as well once.
   Can any one please advise what is the exact issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install the latest update for SharePoint Designer. Check if it works for you.

1.Install SPD SP1:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817441/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-designer-2013-service-pack-1-sp1

2.Then install the latest update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114721/august-2-2016-update-for-sharepoint-designer-2013-kb3114721

Comment: Yes I can, But this is issue is only for a single site. If I publish the workflow for other site, it working fine. Specifically it causing issue When  I am marking checkbox checked options: Start Workflow when an item is created and when an Item is changed. What other issue it can be?

Comment: I reinstalled SharePoint Designer still it is not get work.